# Why are man pages not filling all the space in the terminal?

Tags: manpage, pager

When I run `man` in xterm on Ubuntu 14.04 it looks like this:

[image: yellow-on-white text showing output that fills about 2/3 of the window widthwise]

The lines are wrapped without filling the terminal width. Why?

Comment: Try resizing the terminal *before* you run the `man malloc` command

Comment: @Zanna `14.04` and `xterm`

Comment: @CharlesGreen nothing new happened.

Comment: What are the outputs of `type man` and `echo $MANWIDTH`, `echo $COLUMNS`, `echo $MANPAGER`, `echo $PAGER`?

Comment: I checked in 16.04 LTS, and the manual pages fill the terminal width. There seems to be a glitch in your 14.04 LTS.

Comment: @sudodus Mine works fine on 14.04.

Comment: @wjandrea, yes *your* 14.04, but not *alhelal's* 14.04 ;-) Let us hope steeldriver's tips can help solve the problem.

Comment: @steeldriver for output click [output](https://imgur.com/a/0cE2W)

Comment: here I see `echo &COLUMNS` outputs `124` but I set it `155` [check](https://imgur.com/a/2mfXQ). my terminal holds maximum 124 char per line .

Comment: @wjandrea It also works fine on my 14.04 some days ago.

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/man` behave as expected? why do you even have a `/usr/local/bin/man`?

Comment: @steeldriver I don't know. Should I delete `/usr/local/bin/man`?

Comment: No - please don't randomly delete stuff at this point. Let's try to figure out why/what you have.